# JavaScript deleting all other elements

Tags: javascript, html

So I am working in Chatango's profile HTML embedding and it was going really smoothly until i added my javascript to automate the background image. Once I put the script into the site it erased all other code in the body, head and everything else. This is one section of it as an example of what I am doing.

```
<style type="text/css">
.centerImage
{
position:absolute;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">

day=new Date()     //..get the date

x=day.getHours()    //..get the hour

if (x>=0 && x<1) {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '195',
          width: '260',
          videoId: 'Videolink',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
           event.target.setVolume(0);
       event.target.playVideo();
      }
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                  done = true;
        }
           event.target.setVolume(2);
      }
   document.write('<div id="player"></div><img src="BG.img" class="centerImage" alt="what image shows" >')
}
</script>
```

Its launching a video along side of it but that also doesn't work... This is my output

```
<html><head></head><body><div id="player"></div>
<img src="BG.img" 
class="centerImage" alt="what image shows"></body></html>
```

Mind you this works just fine in the W3school test platform.

Comment: Interestingly the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) advises to to call `document.close()` after using `document.write` to, as they put it, `tell the browser to finish loading the page`. A possibility?

Comment: If memory serves correctly, `document.write` overwrites the entire page. It doesn't append to it. What I recommend doing instead is appending a `<div>` to the end of the page (or wherever you want it), and populating it with your data using `innerHTML`. :)

Comment: Not sure how to do that Brandon, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Although it might have not caused the issue but still it is a good practice to end your javascript statements with a semicolon. Made a couple of changes to your code. It works for me, hope it works for you as well.

```
<style type="text/css">
.centerImage
{
position:absolute;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
      day = new Date(); //..get the date

      x = day.getHours(); //..get the hour

      if (x >= 0) {
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '195',
            width: '260',
            videoId: 'Videolink',
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
          });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
          event.target.setVolume(0);
          event.target.playVideo();
        }
        var done = false;

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            done = true;
          }
          event.target.setVolume(2);
        }
        document.write('<div id="player"></div><img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg" class="centerImage" alt="what image shows" >');
      }

      function loadPlayer() {
        window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
      }

    </script>

    <body onload='loadPlayer();'>
    </body>
```

Cheers!

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hefn73Lo/

Comment: Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong more then a few times here but I took Brandon's advice and went with Inner-html. It was a learning curve but it was pretty simple once you understood the basics of it. Document.write takes over the page, for people that want to know.
This was the final product that ended up working flawlessly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.centerImage
{
position:absolute;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
</style>


<audio id="myAudio" preload="auto" onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()" autoplay>
    <source src="blank" type="audio/mp3"></source>
</audio>
<audio id="myAudio2" preload="auto" onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()" autoplay>
    <source src="blank" type="audio/mp3"></source>
</audio>
<audio id="myAudio3" preload="auto" onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()" autoplay>
    <source src="blank" type="audio/mp3"></source>
</audio>
<audio id="myAudio4" preload="auto" onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()" autoplay>
    <source src="blank" type="audio/mp3"></source>
</audio>
<audio id="myAudio5" preload="auto" onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()" autoplay>
    <source src="blank" type="audio/mp3"></source>
</audio>

<img id="static" class="centerImage" alt="what image shows">

<script>
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
myAudio.play(); myAudio.volume = 0.2;
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio2");
myAudio.play(); myAudio.volume = 1.0;
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio3");
myAudio.play(); myAudio.volume = 1.0;
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio4");
myAudio.play(); myAudio.volume = 1.0;
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio5");
myAudio.play(); myAudio.volume = 1.0;
var day=new Date()     //..get the date
var x=day.getHours()    //..get the hour
if (x>=0 && x<1) {
document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio2").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio3").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio4").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio5").src = "none";
document.getElementById("static").src = "image";
} else
if (x>=1 && x<4) {
document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio2").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio3").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio4").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio5").src = "none";
document.getElementById("static").src = "image";
} else
if (x>=4 && x<6) {
document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio2").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio3").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio4").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio5").src = "none";
document.getElementById("static").src = "image";
} else
if (x>=6 && x<12) {
document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio2").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio3").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio4").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio5").src = "none";
document.getElementById("static").src = "image";
} else
if (x>=12 && x<20) {
document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio2").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio3").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio4").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio5").src = "none";
document.getElementById("static").src = "image";
} else
if (x>=20 && x<24) {
document.getElementById("myAudio").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio2").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio3").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio4").src = "none";
document.getElementById("myAudio5").src = "none";
document.getElementById("static").src = "image";
}
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Yes I have 5 players ready to be loaded in case i need them.